# Assets loaded using AJAX based jQuery Mobile's page navigation model have wrong URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

**Summary:**

Assets have wrong url when I load them using AJAX based jQuery Mobile's page navigation model.

**Scenario:**

2 websites:

- mydomain.com -> normal site (no  problem here, forget it)
- mydomain.com/mobile -> mobile site

**Implementation:**

All the mobile pages have a clean URL like mydomain.com/mobile/page
 i.e: [mydomain.com/mobile/home](http://mydomain.com/mobile/home) , [mydomain.com/mobile/aboutus](http://mydomain.com/mobile/aboutus) , [mydomain.com/mobile/contact](http://mydomain.com/mobile/contact) ,...

So all the mobile pages have inside their "head" seccion a base URL like

```
<base href="mydomain.com/mobile/" />
```

in order for all assets to work with relative (and clean) URLs.

**What works:**

When accessing pages using the full URL, or disabling jQuery Mobile's page navigation model (`$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false`) everything (links,assets) works like a charm.

**The problem:**

When I don't disable jQuery Mobile's page navigation model, the first mobile page I open works fine, but after that, whenever I follow a link in the page, the new page is loaded via Ajax and injected into the DOM, but all the
 assets/links with relative (and clean) URL stop working. They have a wrong URL.

**Example:**

When I visit [mydomain.com/mobile/aboutus](http://mydomain.com/mobile/aboutus) the "*aboutus*" has a logo image with the relative url *logo.png* (the absolute would be [mydomain.com/mobile/logo.png](http://mydomain.com/mobile/logo.png)) that is properly displayed. But when I visit [mydomain.com/mobile/home](http://mydomain.com/mobile/home) and I click a link to [mydomain.com/mobile/aboutus](http://mydomain.com/mobile/aboutus), the "*aboutus*" page is loaded but the logo image url is changed to *aboutlogo.png*  instead of the correct one *logo.png*

**Reference:**
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

> Another key ingredient to jQuery
>   Mobile's page navigation model is the
>   base element, which is injected into
>   the head and modified on every page
>   change to ensure that any assets
>   (css,images,js,etc) referenced on that
>   page will be requested from a proper
>   path. In browsers that don't support
>   dynamic updates to the base element
>   (such as Firefox 3.6), jQuery Mobile
>   loops through all of the referenced
>   assets on the page and prefixes their
>   href and src attributes with the base
>   path.

**Question:**

¿Am I doing it wrong?¿is that a bug or I missunderstood the documentation¿how can I get the assets loaded via AJAX to have the right url?.

I want to use jQuery Mobile's page navigation model in order to have the fancy transitions in the mobile browsers.

**Show me the code!:**

[mydomain.com/mobile/home](http://mydomain.com/mobile/home) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <base href="http://mydomain.com/mobile/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">Foo</div><!--header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="about">About us</a>
        </div><!--content -->

        <div data-role="footer">Bar</div><!--footer -->
    </div><!--page -->
</body>
</html>
```

[mydomain.com/mobile/about](http://mydomain.com/mobile/about) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <base href="http://mydomain.com/mobile/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="about" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">Foo</div><!--header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <img src="logo.png" alt=""/><!--broken when loaded via AJAX-->
            <a href="home" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a><!--broken when loaded via AJAX-->
        </div><!--content -->

        <div data-role="footer">Bar</div><!--footer -->
    </div><!--page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and i think i have found a solution

i belive jQuery Mobile messes with the base url, i found some old documentation that talks about its **"base url management sistem"**

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/#docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html

If you use URLs that are relative to your root directory (with a "/" at the beginning) all the images load correctly..

in your case using the following code should work:

```
<img src="/mobile/logo.png" alt=""/>
```

i know it would be better to have clean relative URL's but i don't think jquery mobile supports them right now

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fortes but it didn't help.My images are relative to my base url (ydomain.com/mobile/), which is different from my root directory (ydomain.com/). Even if I set images src to something with a "/" at the beginning the result is the same.

Comment: maybe you cant use Base url because of what the docs say: **jQuery Mobile manages http requests using a combination of generated absolute URL paths and manipulating a generated <base> element's href attribute. The combination of these two approaches allows us to create URLs that contain full path information for loading pages, and a base element to properly direct asset requests made by those loaded pages (such as images and stylesheets).**

Answer (score 0):

Create a global function on the server-side that takes a relative asset as an argument and outputs the full path to the file. In PHP, something like:

```
function abso($asset){
    return "http://ydomain.com/mobile/" . $asset;
}
```

Then, in your jQuery Mobile page, you could write:

```
<img src="<?= abso('mobile/logo.png');?>" alt=""/>
```

If you happen to be using a framework, there's probably already a function for you. In CodeIgniter, it's `site_url()`.